# Emulate curl -F with retrofit2

Tags: java, android, image, upload, retrofit2

I upload an image to a server using curl -F datafile="@myIMage.png" http://www.myUrl.com/tools/index.php/testUpload/do_upload I have to replicate this upload using an http call in android, I'm using retrofit and this is my code:

```
    public static class NetworkClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://myUrl.com/tools/index.php/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient(Context context) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .build();
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}

public interface UploadAPIs {
    @Multipart
    @POST("/testUpload/do_upload")
    Call<SimpleAdapter> uploadAttachment(@Part MultipartBody.Part filePart);
}

    carica.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Retrofit retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient(getApplicationContext());
            UploadAPIs uploadAPIs = retrofit.create(UploadAPIs.class);

            //path is my image (is a file)
            MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("datafile", path.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), path));

            Call<SimpleAdapter> call = uploadAPIs.uploadAttachment(filePart);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<SimpleAdapter>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<SimpleAdapter> call, Response<SimpleAdapter> response) {
                    Log.d("RES", response.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<SimpleAdapter> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

but in this way I can't upload my image, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you *actually* ignoring all failures, or this is just for shorter snippet?

Comment: I'm ignoring all failures

Comment: Then no one will know why your code doesn't work. It's exactly as it should be on conceptual level, and gritty details are unknown.